# Complex charge of a Hertzian Dipole

Tags: electromagnetism, complex-numbers

Im breaking my head over the solution of an old exam problem:
Given is the following hertzian dipole:

[image: Dipole]

Given are also the equations: $I(t) = \Re\left(I_0 e^{j\omega t}\right)$, $Q(t) = \Re\left(\underline{Q} e^{j\omega t}\right)$ and $\frac{dQ}{dt} = I(t)$

The task is now "Calculate $\underline{Q}$"

The (very sparse) solution is as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dQ}{dt} &= I(t) \tag 1 \\
\Re\left(j \omega \underline{Q} e^{j\omega t}\right) &= \Re\left(I_0 e^{j\omega t}\right) \tag 2\\
j \omega \underline{Q}  &= I_0  \tag 3\\
\underline{Q}  &= -j \frac{I_0}{\omega}  \tag 4
\end{align}
$$

Until step 2 everything is clear. But why can I leave away the $\Re()$ in step 3?

Comment: I also find this a bit puzzling. I would start by expanding the complex exponential.   $$j \omega e^{j \omega t} = j \omega (cos (\omega t) + j sin (\omega t) )$$  Then  $$Re(j \omega e^{j \omega t}) = Re(j \omega cos (\omega t) - \omega sin (\omega t)) = - \omega sin(\omega t)$$  By the same treatment the RHS would be $I_{0} cos(\omega t)$.   My only thought is that maybe $Re(j \omega e^{j \omega t})$ means $j  \omega Re(e^{j \omega t})$ and it's just a notation thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I got it:

(In the following I'm using the short notation $Q_0 = \left|\underline{Q}\right|$ and $\phi = \arg{\underline{Q}}$, so that $\underline{Q}=Q_0 e^{j\phi }$)

$$
\begin{align}
\Re{(I_0 e^{j \omega t})} &= \frac{d}{dt} Q(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \Re{(\underline{Q} e^{j \omega t})} = \frac{d}{dt} \Re{(Q_0 e^{j (\omega t + \phi)})} \\
I_0 \cos(\omega t) &= Q_0 \frac{d}{dt} \cos( \omega t + \phi) = -\omega Q_0 \sin( \omega t + \phi) = -\omega Q_0 \cos( \omega t + \phi -\pi/2)\\
I_0 \frac{e^{j \omega t}+e^{-j \omega t}}{2} &= -\omega Q_0 \frac{e^{j (\omega t +\phi -\pi/2)}+e^{-j (\omega t +\phi -\pi/2)}}{2} = -\omega Q_0 e^{\phi} e^{-j\pi/2} \frac{e^{j \omega t}+e^{-j \omega t}}{2} \\
I_0 = j\omega \underline{Q}\\
\underline{Q} = \frac{I_0}{j\omega} 
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

My buest guess: $\underline{Q}$, $j$, $\omega $ and $I_0$ are real constants. Then it would be trivial. But it's hard to tell in the current version of the question since not all symbols are defined.

Comment: Okay let me define it a bit better:
$j=\sqrt{-1}$ is the complex unit. $\omega$, $I_0$ and $t$ are real constants.
$\underline{Q}$ is a complex number. $Q$ (not underlined) however is a real number (underlined = complex, not underlined=real)